# Connecting to DB2 using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, db2

I'm trying to connect to a DB2 database and execute some queries. I had it working a few days ago, but now it's giving some really strange errors and I can't figure out why.

The PowerShell connection code

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=X;HostName=X;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=X;Uid=X;Pwd=X;CurrentSchema=X");
$ds = New-Object "System.Data.DataSet"  

$da = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($QuerySQL, $connection)
$da.Fill($ds)

$ds.Tables[0].Rows |
    select * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, HasErrors, Name, Table, ItemArray |
    Export-Csv "c:\Scripts\results.csv" -encoding "unicode" -notype
```

The error I'm seeing:

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "No error message available, result code: E_UNEXPECTED(0x8000FFFF)."

Anybody got any ideas why this is cropping up?

I've got other scripts that use `Fill()` in the exact same way an don't produce errors, so this is really baffling me!

Comment: I would guess that if your other scripts are using this same pattern to connect to the same DB2 instance, the problem may be with your SQL query.  Can you add it to the question?

Comment: I've executed the query separately and it's works :/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've figured it out.

You need to run powershell as admin to use the DB2 driver. Why this is, I don't know, but that's how I fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the user to the `DB2Users` or `DB2Admns` groups.  The local Administrators group works, too, but for security reasons the other two groups are more appropriate.  These groups are typically created by default on the server to which you install DB2.  They are local groups.