# Need to connect to DB2 database with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, db2

I couldn't get the output for my query which I am trying to run thru PowerShell.

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=IBMDADB2;DSN=;User Id=;Password=");
$ds = New-Object "System.Data.DataSet"
$QuerySQL = "select * from omaa.status"
$da = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($QuerySQL, $connection)
$da.Fill($ds)
```

I am getting this exception

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Unspecified error"
At line:6 char:9
+ $da.Fill <<<< ($ds)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Comment: Duplicate of this --- Connecting to DB2 using powershell
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862005/connecting-to-db2-using-powershell

Comment: I am running as administrator ...still it's throwing this exception @postanote

Comment: Is your user member of one of the groups DB2Users or DB2Admns as the second answer to the other question suggests?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an aging thread, but maybe this will help someone. I'm using this, and it works for Oracle and DB2 connections. (Not with acceleration for DB2 though). Exports CSV, but this can be modified to convert to xlsx afterwards.

```
function Get-OLEDBData ($connectstring, $sql) {            
   $OLEDBConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connectstring)            
   $OLEDBConn.open()            
   $readcmd = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($sql,$OLEDBConn)            
   $readcmd.CommandTimeout = '300'            
   $da = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($readcmd)            
   $dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable            
   [void]$da.fill($dt)            
   $OLEDBConn.close()            
   return $dt            
}

#For Oracle
$connString = "password=yourPassword;User ID=YourID;Data Source=YourServer;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle"            

#For DB2
$connString = "Provider=DB2OLEDB.1;Network Transport Library=TCPIP;Network Address=YourIPHere;Network Port=YourPortHere;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseHere;Package Collection=NULLID;Default Schema=SameAsYourDatabaseHere;User ID=YourID;Password=YourPassword;"            

$qry= "select something from somewhere"

Get-OLEDBData $connString $qry | Export-Csv -Path C:\TargetFolder\Results.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```