# PowerShell DB2 DataTable Row to JSON File for jQuery DataTables

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, datatables, db2

I am running multiple queries against a `DB2 Database` and storing the information in `ArrayList`. However, the information returned is `DataTable`, due to where I obtained the code for querying the `DB2 Database`.

What I am doing is querying the results on a schedule, pushing the information to a `JSON` File that a `jQuery` DataTables will read to populate the results with. Converting to a `JSON Object` works, however, it is missing a parent node of 'data' so that `jQuery` can see the results.

Here is the data that is produced, a sample at least:

```
[ {
    "A":  "1",
    "B":  "2",
    "C":  "3",
    "D":  "4"
} ]
```

However, `jQuery DataTables` expects data as the parent node to load the data.
So, what I am trying to do is get the json to look like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "A":  "1",
            "B":  "2",
            "C":  "3",
            "D":  "4"
        }
        ]
}
```

This is the function I am using to get the results from `DB2`:

```
Function Get-DB2Results { 
param (
    $db2
)
$script:dbcmd.CommandText = $db2
$rdr = $script:dbcmd.ExecuteReader()
$dt = [System.Data.DataTable]::New()
$dt.Load($rdr)
Return $dt
}
```

I am storing this information in a ArrayList. I believe because the mix of objects, the data is not converting right when I export to `JSON`:

```
Connect-DB2
foreach ($query in $SQLArray) { 
    $jsonFileTotals.add(((Get-DB2Results -db2 $query) | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors))
    $jsonFileTotals.add($blankLine)
}
Disconnect-DB2
@{ data = @( $jsonFileTotals.toArray() ) } | ConvertTo-Json | out-file \\SRV01\Data\totalsArray.txt -force
```

I believe because there is an `ArrayList` & `DataTable` object mixed, an incorrect `JSON` file:

```
             "@{A=1; B=8; C=10; D=9}"
         ],
         {
             "A":  "1",
             "B":  "2",
             "C":  "3",
             "D":  "4",
```

Am I over complicating the issue? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi can you please explain me how you connected to db2 in powershell ? Do you use powershell 7 or 5?

Comment: @user3898488 as for `'explain me how you connected to db2 in powershell ? Do you use powershell 7 or 5?'` PS version does not matter. Connecting to any DB has specific connection string criteria. There are lots of examples/articles, all over the web. ['PowerShell connect to db2'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+connect+too+db2%27&t=h_&ia=web), with [SO post as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862005/connecting-to-db2-using-powershell)., and this article sample [PS connect to DB2](https://datageek.blog/en/2018/08/09/hello-db2-world-powershell/)

Comment: For me its not so easy; particulary if you work with V7 as (at least some time ago) the db2 driver where not too good, see here: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/hybriddatamanagement/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=7be8e033-4c24-4de6-b52c-3db1647afe53&CommunityKey=ea909850-39ea-4ac4-9512-8e2eb37ea09a&tab=digestviewer&reply-inline=7be8e033-4c24-4de6-b52c-3db1647afe53&SuccessMsg=Thank%20you%20for%20submitting%20your%20message

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. Can you please check also my comment and give me an hint how to connect to db2 in powershell?

```
$MyArrayList = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"

$MyArrayList.Add(5)
$MyArrayList.Add(5)
$MyArrayList.Add(5)
$MyArrayList.Add(5)
$MyArrayList.Add(4)

$MyArrayList | ConvertTo-Json

$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    data = $MyArrayList
}

$myObject | ConvertTo-Json

#or even lighter
$myHashTable= @{}
$myHashTable.data = $MyArrayList
$myHashTable | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Thank you! I did just that to solve my issue! I appreciate the help! 

Here is where I got information on connecting to DB2: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/DB2/comments/e70c27/db2_and_powershell/