Any tool or command to export meta-data from iBM DB2 Webquery to file eg. XML?
Would like to export ALL META-DATA from existing iBM-i DB2 Webquery to file eg. .xml type of file for a client as they want to have their webquery reports meta-data migrated to other solutions. They are on iBM-i AS400 series
Any tool or commands I can use to do this?
Any help is GREATLY Appreciated!! I had been searching but unable to find any answer.
Any tool or command to export meta-data from iBM DB2 Webquery to file eg. XML?

You can use PS to query the DB2 database (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862005/connecting-to-db2-using-powershell).  Then there are lot of methods in PS to export to XML.

According the the Web Query Backup guide
• Synonyms
Also referred to as metadata. All synonyms are stored under the Integrated File System
(IFS) directory /QIBM/UserData/qwebqry/apps.
• Reports
Also known as fexs or focexecs, these are the reports, documents and dashboards
created via Web Query. These items reside in database tables in library QWQREPOS.
You can take a peek in those locations and see if it's a format you can read.
Also note that IBM i Web Query is a rebranded Informational Builders product.  Info you find for IBI may be applicable.
